# Angular and Spring rest api communication over https

Tags: javascript, java, angular, spring, ssl

I have frontend written in angular and backend written in Spring. I bought hosting and there I installed tomcat where im deploying my production backend. Im deploying frontend under domain folder on my hosting service.
Spring has jks certificate. I added this jks certificate to connectors in server.xml.
Angular has let's encrypt certificate which was generated for my domain "spotmapa.pl".

Now i have this situation:
On desktop google chrome my domain seems "not secure" and when this website makes api calls for backend it does it correct.
But in for example firefox my domain seems secure and has padlock but api calls to backend not working from there.

My api calls to backend from postman works properly, but doesnt work from secured by lets encrypt website.
I dont get any errros in logs.

I have two questions:
Should i have the same certificate for backend and frontend?
Why does unsecured origins make api calls right, but secured website https://spotmapa.pl no?

Answer (score 0):

Frontend with lets encrypt was calling api secured by selfsigned certificate. This caused problem. I did lets encrypt for the backend too and it works correctly.